# How to thread these two if statements?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
    void quickSort (int *array, size_t low, size_t high)
{
    size_t index = partition(array, low, high);
    
    if(index > low + 1)
        quickSort(array, low, index - 1); // left side of pivot
    if(index + 1 < high)
        quickSort(array, index + 1, high); // right side of pivot
}
```

usually: threading is done like this ( code below is example of how it should be done) ... but in the code above I run into the issue that I have two if conditions. Would it be possible to put those two if conditions into one umbrella and then stop one of them if its condition is met?

```
std::thread left (quickSortThreaded1,array, low, index - 1);
std::thread right (quickSortThreaded1,array, index + 1, high);
left.join();
right.join();
```

They are working on different parts of an array, so there shouldn't be a problem with race condition or it using information from the other thread.

Comment: Btw the overhead of starting and then tearing down threads can be considerable, so once you have this working, you may find that it doesn't speed things up much (or even slows things down) except in the case where each thread is operating on a relatively large amount of data.  If so, you might then want to put in some conditional logic so that you only spawn threads when there's enough data present to make it worthwhile to do so.

Comment: I'm taking a beginners c++ class, and barely even touched threading, using atomic and all that I'm not really sure how to do. I'll try to look into it!

Comment: To your second comment, yup professor did mention using threads is only useful for large amount of data

Answer (score 1):

I think the only real problem you need to solve here is the fact that `std::thread` launches from its child thread from the `std::thread` object's constructor, which can be awkward to do conditionally when declaring the `std::thread` object on the stack.  In this case I'd suggest something like this:

```
void quickSort (int *array, size_t low, size_t high)
{
    const size_t index = partition(array, low, high);

    const bool doLeft       = (index > low + 1)
    const bool doRight      = (index + 1 < high);
    const bool spawnThreads = ((doLeft)&&(doRight));  // maybe add e.g. &&((high-low)>50000)) at some point
    if (spawnThreads)
    {
       // multi-threaded implementation
       std::thread left (quickSortThreaded1,array, low, index - 1);
       std::thread right (quickSortThreaded1,array, index + 1, high);
       left.join();
       right.join();
    }
    else
    {
       // single-threaded implementation
       if (doLeft)  quickSort(array, low, index - 1); // left side of pivot
       if (doRight) quickSort(array, index + 1, high); // right side of pivot
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the code just a tiny bit, moving the condition:

```
void quickSort (int *array, size_t low, size_t high)
{
    if (low >= high)
        return;
    size_t index = partition(array, low, high);
    quickSort(array, low, index - 1);
    quickSort(array, index + 1, high);
}
```

and the transformation is simple.